# Matlab issues - find the value closest to average value

Tags: matlab

I'm currently having some problems with some Matlab exercises we have to do at university. May be you can help.

There is an array x of about 100 numbers and I now have to find the one which is the closest to the average value of the array.
I have no clue how to do that - could you help me?

Comment: What have you tried? You could start off by finding the average and finding how far each point is from it

Comment: Please show us your code. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways you could approach this, first say you have a vector of 100 in length:

```
 A = randi(100,1,100); %generate 100 random ints
 Mu = mean(A) %mean of A

 %for example - subtract by mean and take abs
 B = abs(A-Mu); 
 [C idx] = min(B); %index of closest value
 result = A(idx);  %closest value


 %Another method perhaps:
 [sortA indA]= sort(A); %sort A
 [N,bin]=histc(Mu,sortA); %use histc to find the bin closest
 index=bin+1; 
  if abs(Mu-sortA(bin))<abs(Mu-sortA(bin+1))

    fclosest=sortA(bin)
    index=bin;
  else
    fclosest=sortA(index)

  end
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Define an Array A
2. Sum the defined array A
3. Find the average = sum(A) / length(A)
4. Find the difference = average - A(i)  % using loop
5. Find the minimum of the difference = min(difference)
6. Finding the location of step 5 above in the array will give you the answer..

This is a very simple problem ! Hope this will help,...

Answer (score 0):

That's not really a hard question, now is it? Search for the mean using the `mean`-command. Now calculate the difference between your array and the mean, and determine the minimal value using

```
    [min_value, index] = min(abs(difference));
```